# Cartography on LaTeX

Tags: fonts

How to use the cartography font mencioned in http://ctan.tche.br/info/fontsampler/sampler.pdf

Answer (score 15):

Now, this looks to be a little-known font ;-)

Fascinatingly, there are metafont sources for this in TeXLive, but it seems there's no LaTeX support and it also doesn't feature in the "Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List".

Well, let's start from the beginning.

If you open the web directory above the link you gave,

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/fontsampler

you find the TeX source of the PDF. There, the font is used like this:

```
\thefont[U]{Cartography}{zka}{A\thinspace B\thinspace C\thinspace
D\thinspace E\thinspace F\thinspace G\thinspace H\thinspace
I\thinspace J\thinspace K\thinspace L\thinspace M\thinspace
N\thinspace O\thinspace P\thinspace Q\thinspace R\thinspace
S\thinspace T\thinspace U\thinspace V\thinspace W\thinspace
X\thinspace Y\thinspace Z\thinspace a\thinspace b\thinspace
c\thinspace d\thinspace e\thinspace f\thinspace g\thinspace
h\thinspace i\thinspace j\thinspace k\thinspace
m\thinspace n\thinspace q\thinspace s}
```

`\thefont` is more or less a shorthand for

```
{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{zka}\selectfont A\thinspace B\thinspace C\thinspace
D\thinspace E\thinspace F\thinspace G\thinspace H\thinspace
I\thinspace J\thinspace K\thinspace L\thinspace M\thinspace
N\thinspace O\thinspace P\thinspace Q\thinspace R\thinspace
S\thinspace T\thinspace U\thinspace V\thinspace W\thinspace
X\thinspace Y\thinspace Z\thinspace a\thinspace b\thinspace
c\thinspace d\thinspace e\thinspace f\thinspace g\thinspace
h\thinspace i\thinspace j\thinspace k\thinspace
m\thinspace n\thinspace q\thinspace s}
```

To use the font named `zka` with LaTeX you need the `fd` file in the same directory:

http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/fontsampler/uzka.fd

In there you'll see the real font name used is `karta15` for which a `tfm` and `mf` file should exist in your TeX distribution.

So if `uzka.fd` can be found by TeX you're all set up to use this font (in the `metafont` version, which means you'll get bitmaps in a PDF).

In addition to that, there even is a Type1 version of this font in

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/niceframe

which at least isn't in *my* TeXLive distribution, so you might need to install the package.

After this, you can use the PostScript version of this font with `pdftex` by saying

```
\pdfmapfile{niceframe.map}
```

in the preamble of your document.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you update this? `niceframe` now seems to be included in TeX Live, so you should get type1 by default?